# Set home directory of a user to root?

Tags: linux, root, ftp

I would like to set the home directory for ftpuser to root. That's my command:

```
    # adduser ftproot -shell /bin/false -home /var/www
```

What is the directory term for root?

Comment: Very very bad idea.

Comment: What are alternatives?

Comment: root as in "the home directory of the superuser", or root as in "the Document Root of the web server"?

Comment: Not the directory `/var/www`. It's `/`

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is indeed a bad idea to use the homedirectory of root for other purposes. Consider a dedicated home directory for the new user, root is always able to access it.

Are you indeed looking for setting the homedirectory of the ftp user to the homedirectory of the superuser root or are you looking for a way to safely specify a FTP root (jailed or similar) to isolate the ftp account?

Next, the arguments -shell and -home needs an additional - (--shell, --home). See also `adduser --help`

If you still want to do so, you must ensure that the new user gets access to the homedirectory of root.

Get the current homedirectory of root using `getent passwd root`. The homedirectory is specified in the 6th field (often /root).

Use `--home /root` in your command to specify the homedirectory.